# Meaning of the phrase "gin soaked boy"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Referring to the song *Gin Soaked Boy* by Divine comedy, what does the phrase "Gin in the Gin Soaked Boy" mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an adequate answer rests not on general linguistic considerations but on intratextual paradigms and intertextual allusions peculiar to this specific work --in a word, on LitCrit.

Comment: the intention of the question was not only to know the meaning of the phrase, but also to know if infact such a phrase exists (idiom or proverb etc ) now sure if that still categorizes the question as intratextual paradigms.

Comment: As @Hank says, *gin-soaked boy* is a reference to the Tom Waits song of that title, in which the gin-soaked boy with whom the singer believes his wife is having an affair is always characterized as *some gin-soaked boy **that you don't know***, so poetically *the gin-soaked boy* designates an attractive miscreant of impenetrable identity; the *gin*, then, is the source of both Hannon's systematically self-contradictory identity and its impenetrability. None of these 'meanings' derives from the words themselves -- which is why questions like this are off-topic!

Comment: gotcha.. really should have read the posting rules.. *yeiks*. But thanks a lot for the clarification of the phrase. :) kudos

Comment: There are lots of questions about poetry and song lyrics that *are* fundamentally linguistic -- this one just happens to be fundamentally LitCrit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an interview with **[Rock Sucker](http://rocksucker.co.uk/2010/07/divine-comedy-230710.html)**, the following question and answer occurred:

> **Q: On a similar note, did you ever divulge the meaning behind ‘Gin Soaked Boy’?**
>
> A: I think I did. You know what, the first person who got it was my mum, which I thought was brilliant as she clearly knows the workings of my mind! The answer is ‘spirit’. Gin, spirit, you know…and you can go through all the other ones, pretty much. That’s certainly what I was thinking. Usually people go, “Uh?”

The song is a riddle that ends in the question, *"Well, who am I?"*. Neil Hannon answers this riddle in the interview, saying that the answer to the riddle is *spirit*. So, *Gin* was a reference to ***spirit*** in the sense that Gin is an alcoholic spirit.

Hannon wasn't clear on the actual meaning of the full phrase "Gin Soaked Boy", but he is not the first user of that phrase. It is a reference to the song ["Gin Soaked Boy"](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tel26vjrg2cc7rtzgxby5usj3yi?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics) by Tom Waits. In this song, it is referencing a wife who is accused of cheating on her husband with *"some gin-soaked boy that you don't know"*.

The only definition I have found to go off of is one from [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gin-soaked):

> #### Gin-Soaked
>
> *informal adjective*
>
> - Habitually drunk on gin.